# finding twitter accounts associated with a topic

Tags: twitter, machine-learning

I was asked to find Twitter accounts associated with the `Dominican Republic` (the project had to do with voting).  This was a strange request since some twitter accounts have GeoSpatial data associated with the account, we have no idea whether it is accurate.

I wound up searching by hand for keywords that I knew were related: `#dominican`, `#washingtonheights` and I hopped along their friends and followers and I found the people I was looking for.

---

#### More genereally:

How do I search for Twitter accounts associated with a given topic?  **How might it be possible to train a bot to identify hashtags relevant to a given topic?**  And then we can search for those keywords.

---

*@Moderators*: This is not really a coding question.  If you can think of a better StackExchange, please migrate this!

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a given Topic i would suggest he following:

1. Get a couple of Account by Hand by these Hashtags you already mentioned.
2. Retrieve X tweets for these Accounts
3. Do some Natural Language Processing of these Tweets to get new ideas for Keywords.

Some things i used in this/similar contex:

- tf-idf + NMF to get Topics and then sort by components to retrieve
  the topics a user is talking about (user can have multiple topics).
- some sort of clustering (your biggest problem here will be the high
  sparesity of the data, so PCA could be an option)
- use wordnet etc to collect similar keywords